# How to access Query-replace history in replace format (for eg: "ABC → XYZ")

Tags: search, query-replace

I have enabled query replace save history as below. When I am in query-replace mode, I see previous search-replace patterns of the current session in the form "ABC -> XYZ". But the search-replace patterns from previous emacs sessions dont show up as "LMN -> PQR" instead they show up as LMN for search pattern and then I need to again search for PQR as replace pattern. Is there a way to improve this?

```
;;Save Search history                                                                                                                                                 
(setq savehist-additional-variables                                                                                                                                   
      '(search-ring regexp-search-ring compile-history)                                                                                                               
      savehist-file "~/.emacs.d/savehist")                                                                                                                            
(savehist-mode t)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The history of query-replace replacement pairs can be saved by adding `query-replace-defaults` (and also optionally `query-replace-history`) to `savehist-additional-variables`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @link0ff, it works..